# Python:Split string to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string separated by comma(,) which contains list, integer,boolean and string. How to convert this to a list. 
For example,

```
s= "[{'Name':'key','Values':['data']}],6,True,'somestring'"
```

I want to convert this to list as below in Python(3.5v)

```
[[{'Name':'key','Values':['data']}],6,True,'somestring']
```

The problem here is, when i tried to split it based on comma, the items inside list get divided. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast
s= "[{'Name':'key','Values':['data']}],6,True,'somestring'"
print(list(ast.literal_eval(s)))

# [[{'Name': 'key', 'Values': ['data']}], 6, True, 'somestring']
```

Comment: If there is only a single value as input either integer or boolean, this is throwing error
`>>> s= "6"
>>> b=list(ast.literal_eval(s))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>>`
and

`>>> s="True"
>>> b=list(ast.literal_eval(s))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
>>>`

Comment: and with single string too:
`>>> s="somerolename"
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python 3.5.4\lib\ast.py", line 84, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "C:\Python 3.5.4\lib\ast.py", line 83, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x01065CD0>`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710393/malformed-string-while-using-ast-literal-eval and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630323/typeerrorbool-object-is-not-iterable-when-trying-to-return-a-boolean and

Answer (score 0):

You can use `literal_eval` method from `ast` module

```
s="[{'Name':'key','Values':['data']}],6,True,'somestring'"
list(ast.literal_eval(s))
```

## Out

```
[[{'Name': 'key', 'Values': ['data']}], 6, True, 'somestring']
```